# Remove White spaces from end of string in windows phone 8 XAML and C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a property in a ViewModel called Message, a textbox is bound to it in TwoWay. How can I remove white spaces from the end of whatever string of text is bound to it.

```
private string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref message, value);
        }
    }
```

My set Property is defined like this

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Try using [Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx). The only problem is that it also removes spaces from the front.

Comment: If one of the answers worked for you, then you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want the TrimEnd method.

```
private string message;
public string Message
{
    get
    {
        return message;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref message, value.TrimEnd());
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

in the get method put

```
get
    {
        return message.TrimEnd();
    }
```